# some registers can't get with sql

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to get a count with these query. I would like that it shows me all nameHost (althought the count was 0) but with these query, the nameHost that the count is 0 not shows me nameHost.
Could you help me please?

```
 select a.nameHost, count(b.job_name) as cuenta
                from jobsDefinition b
                         right join cmdmzpre.nodes a
                        on b.node_id in (a.nodeid,a.nameHost) 
                         where b.app not like 'UNPLAN' group by a.nameHost order by a.nameHost desc;
```

Example of tables:

```
nodes         
=======
nameHost        nodeid
---------       -------
a               a
b               b
b               f
e               g



jobsDefinition
================
node_id        job_name
----------     -----------
a               fruit
b               apple
c               iron
a               banana
f               orange
```

The output would be:

```
a 2 (fruit,banana)
b 2 (apple,orange)
e 0
```

Comment: can you post your sample dataset and expected results set.

Comment: you sure that ON condition is correct? What is the correlation between both tables?

Comment: I edit the main post to see how would be the output

Comment: From your dataset, `a` should be 2. Why you put 1. Any reason.

Comment: Sorry you have reason, I update the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, `From your dataset, **a** should be **2**.`

Use this query:

```
  ---Table Data start ----

WITH nodes (nameHost, nodeid)
     AS (SELECT 'a', 'a' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'b', 'b' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'b', 'f' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'e', 'g' FROM DUAL),
     jobdef (node_id, job_name)
     AS (SELECT 'a', 'fruit' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'b', 'apple' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'c', 'iron' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'a', 'banana' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'f', 'orange' FROM DUAL)
  --Table data end---
  --Actual Query
  SELECT n.namehost,
         COUNT (jd.node_id) AS Cnt,
         LISTAGG (jd.job_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) JB_NM
    FROM nodes n 
    LEFT JOIN jobdef jd 
    ON n.nodeid = jd.node_id
GROUP BY n.namehost
ORDER BY namehost;
```

Comment: Wooo! it works. You are a guru! Could you explain me how you do it? What did I do bad? Thanks!

Comment: @user8957934 Nothing extraordinary. I just used Left Join to get the desired result and you wer using Right join.  All you need to know about the joins :-)

Comment: Sorry I dont put the complete question!!!! :-( . The problem is that if I put other where in jd table (for instance jd.app = 'TRY') and don't find it. I would like that it shows me these namehost with 0 in the count. And now, with these query, don't shows me the register

Comment: @user8957934 You must put question clearly. I mean you should not expect answer in piecewise. You had put the above Dataset and resultset. I showed you how you can proceed. Now you have to work on your requirement, We cannot help you completing your job. We can only show you how you can achieve it. Check as your data is somehting is missing or not satsfying the condition

Comment: Sorry I answer your question and I put other with the correct question ok? Thanks for your time

Comment: @user8957934 You must show more correct data set and show what and how you tried and what is not working

Comment: Sorry again.  Thanks for your  help